# Is it possible to return a std::initializer_list from a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, return-value, stdinitializerlist

The following works:

```
struct A {
    int i;
    int v;
};

std::initializer_list<A> getList() {
    return {A{0,1}, A{2,3}};
}

int main() {
    auto list = getList();
}
```

I can verify that the contents of list is correct.

However, if I change the member `v` to a `std::vector`, it does not work:

```
struct A {
    int i;
    std::vector<int> v;
};

std::initializer_list<A> getList() {
    return {A{0,{1,2}}, A{3,{4,5}}};
}
```

in this case, the returned list contains junk values.

I know the standard says that the underlaying objects are not copied when a `std::initializer_list` is copied. Is this what happens here?

Why did it work in the first example? Was it luck? Is it something special with the case when the objects in the list contains a `std::vector`?

Comment: g++ says `In function 'std::initializer_list<A> getList()':
warning: returning temporary 'initializer_list' does not extend the lifetime of the underlying array [-Winit-list-lifetime]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning `initializer_list` compiles, but it seldom does the right thing. The list is a temporary value and the `initializer_list` object points to it. It is a dangling pointer.

In your first example, an optimization is applied because the list is a constant expression. Instead of being written into temporary storage, it is a static global. However, this optimization is not specified in the standard. The return value working, is only a form of undefined behavior.